# Year of a date in breeze predicate

Tags: breeze

is it possible to use expression in the properties of a predicate (The .Year of the following example) ?

```
var p1 = new Predicate("ContractDate.Year", ">", 12);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update: The bug mentioned below was fixed as of Breeze 1.4.8.

---

You can use any OData function in a Breeze predicate so you can do this:

```
var query = new breeze.EntityQuery()
        .from("Employees")
        .where("year(hireDate)", ">", 1993);
```

Note that there is a bug with **local** queries (i.e. EntityManager.executeQueryLocally) using OData date functions.  This bug will be fixed in the 1.4.8 release, out later this week or next. This bug does not affect server queries.

Comment: hi jay, thanks a lot! was not aware that odata includes this already. it would help to extend the query samples in your docs with just one of this guys :) let me know if it helps if i download and use current github code (i'm querying the local cache)